# Add a Formula to a Cell referencing a Table Column via VBA

Tags: excel, sum, formula, listobject, vba

I'm trying to sum up the column of a table on a second worksheet in a cell on the first worksheet via VBA.  I have tried to push in the formula using the .Formula property, but the cell is left blank.

For this question, assume that the table resides on Worksheet("Data") and is named "Table1".  The Column in question is [APAC].  xlsheet is defined earlier in the code and is confirmed to be working as expected.  With this in mind, the VBA to populate the formula I have used is as follows:

```
xlsheet.Range("C8").Formula = "=Sum(Table1[APAC])"
```

The above formula when manually typed into the cell itself works like a charm, but for some reason doing this via VBA is not accpeted.

I have even tried to use the .FormulaR1C1 property, but received the same results.

I was hoping that by using a Table I could easily reference an entire table column for my calculations to summarize the data stored within it via VBA, but it doesn't seem to like it.  Has anyone else run into this error or have any workarounds/solutions?  Thanks in advance!

There is one thing I forgot to mention and it is probably a BIG item to mention.  I am generating my data from MS Access 2010 and using MS Access VBA to format the Excel Output.  For the most part, the VBA used in Excel will be the same, with the exception of late binding the 2010 Excel Application.

More of the code coming from MS Access to MS Excel ... can't show all of it, as there is so much done by Access first before exporting to Excel that would be way too much:

```
        'Filename is the string with the link to the file
        Set xlbook = GetObject(filename)

        'Disable Screen Updating until all editing is complete
        'xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Make sure excel is visibe on the screen
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlbook.Windows(1).Visible = True

        'Rename the existing worksheet to Data
        xlbook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Data"

        'Set populated data on Data worksheet as a Table
        With xlbook.Worksheets("Data")
            'Get the Last Row and Column to determine the final populated cell to be included in the Table
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'Set the populated data as Table1
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"

        End With

        'Add a new worksheet
        With xlbook
            .Worksheets.Add .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count), , 1
            .Worksheets(1).Name = "Reports"
        End With

        Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets("Reports")

        With xlsheet
            With .Range("A1:A5")
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Size = 14
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            End With
            .Range("B1:B5").Font.Size = 14

            .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Report:"
            .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = rpt
            .Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Region:"
            .Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = region
            .Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "System:"
            .Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = Sys
            .Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "Program/Funding Source:"
            .Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = prog
            If rpt = "Request Delivered" Or rpt = "Requests Received" Then
                .Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "Year:"
                .Range("B5").FormulaR1C1 = Yr
                Else
                    .Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete   'Not needed for the other reports
            End If
            .Columns(1).AutoFit
        End With


        'Define the current sheet in the workbook as xlSheet
        Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)



'**********************************************************************************************************************************

        'Use Select case to Go to appropriate formatting code
        Select Case rpt
            Case "Approved for Target Staging", "In Process"
                With xlsheet
                    .Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 30
                    With .Range("B7:C7")
                        .Font.Size = 12
                        .Font.Bold = True
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                    End With
                    With .Range("B7")
                        .Select
                        .FormulaR1C1 = rpt
                        .Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "APAC"
                        .Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1([APAC])"   '<--- HERE IS ONE OF THEM
                        .Offset(2, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "EMEA"
                        .Offset(2, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1([EMEA])"   '<-- ANOTHER
                        .Offset(3, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "LATAM"
                        .Offset(3, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1([LATAM])"   '<-- ETC.
                        .Offset(4, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "NAM"
                        .Offset(4, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1([NAM])"   '<-- ETC.
                        .Offset(5, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Global"
                        .Offset(5, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1([GLOBAL])"   '<-- ETC.
                        .Offset(6, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
                        .Offset(6, 1).Formula = "=Sum(C8:C12)"
                    End With
                End With


            Case "Request Delivered", "Requests Received"

        End Select
```

Comment: shouldn't the formula be `=SUM(Table1[APAC])`  I think you have an extra `(`

Comment: Scott ... you are right, I put in the extra ( by accident.  I'll remove it from here, but the problem still stands.

Comment: Can you show more of your code because it works for me as is.  I get the proper formula in the proper cell.

Comment: Sure Scott.  Added the code specifically for the MS Excel portion ... no need to display all the MS Access specific code.  Take note that I am using an "Offset" vs. the actual defined cell range.  I figured if I can get the defined cell range to work, I could modify it for the Offset as well.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break in and stepping through to make sure the Case fires like it should and you do not have a typo?

Comment: and your code you just posted still has the extra `(` in all the formulas.

Comment: Yes ... I should have mentioned that.  I have stepped through and it does add the region values "APAC, EMEA, LATAM, NAM, Global, and Total" in the B Column and then the only formula that is successfully added is the "=Sum(C8:C12)".  So the .Formula does work, but it just doesn't like using the Table and Column.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH!!!!!  Yep, the extra ( in all the formulas was the problem ... [banging head against desk].  Thanks Scott!

Comment: This should have been solved 52 minutes ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Scott was the genius that noticed that I left an extra ( in all of my formulas.  Once removed, they worked with no problem at all.  So the below section of code works now.  Thanks Scott!

```
With .Range("B7")
                        .Select
                        .FormulaR1C1 = rpt
                        .Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "APAC"
                        .Offset(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(Table1[APAC])"
                        .Offset(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = .Worksheet("Data").ListObject("Table1").ListColumns("APAC")
                        .Offset(2, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "EMEA"
                        .Offset(2, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1[EMEA])"
                        .Offset(3, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "LATAM"
                        .Offset(3, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1[LATAM])"
                        .Offset(4, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "NAM"
                        .Offset(4, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1[NAM])"
                        .Offset(5, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Global"
                        .Offset(5, 1).Formula = "=Sum(Table1[GLOBAL])"
                        .Offset(6, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
                        .Offset(6, 1).Formula = "=Sum(C8:C12)"
                    End With
```